# Can't figure out what is wrong with my inventory in my text-base game

Tags: python, inventory, text-based

So I want to be able to remove and add items in an inventory that I tried creating in my game but I keep receiving an error. This is my code:

```
inventory={}
def add_to_inventory():
    inventory.append()

elif choice == "use h on razor":
        print ("(pick up razor)")
        if "razor" in inventory:
            print ("You already got this item.")
            print ("")
            print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory))
        if "razor" not in inventory:
            print ("You walked over and picked up your razor blade.")
            print ("It's been added to your inventory.")
            add_to_inventory("razor")
            print("")
            print ("Inventory: " + str(inventory))
        game()
```

this is the error that I receive when I run my game:

(pick up razor)
You walked over and picked up your razor blade.
It's been added to your inventory.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 337, in <module>
    instructions_part_1()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 336, in instructions_part_1
    try_1()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 310, in try_1
    instructions_part_2()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 304, in instructions_part_2
    try_2()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 286, in try_2
    instructions_part_3()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 280, in instructions_part_3
    try_3()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 266, in try_3
    instructions_part_4()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 259, in instructions_part_4
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 231, in main
    start()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 219, in start
    game()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 57, in game
    game()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\inferno_junction_2017-10-27.py", line 155, in game
    add_to_inventory("razor")
TypeError: add_to_inventory() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the line skdbelsldjdwlslkdneñsldjdn

Comment: Sorry just a little Friday joke :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Look at the error.  It says `add_to_inventory` takes no arguments.  Yet you tried to pass an argument when calling it.  So make up your mind.  Should it take an argument or not?  If so, then *add it*.  If not, then *don't call it with one*.  It really doesn't get much more basic than this.

Comment: Voting to close - these bugs are at the level of typos (e.g., missing arguments).

Comment: how do you turn it into an argument? Sorry I am new to python...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is occurring because `add_to_inventory` has no parameters in the function definition, but you are trying to pass `'razor'` as an argument to it. That's what `TypeError: add_to_inventory() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`means.

Also, you are using the list `append` method, but you are making inventory a dictionary.

Here are two options that you could use depending on the functionality desired, one for the dictionary and one for the list.

```
#DICTIONARY INVENTORY

from collections import defaultdict
inventory = defaultdict(int)

def add_to_inventory(item, amount):
    inventory[item] += amount

#LIST INVENTORY 

inventory = []
def add_to_inventory(item):
    inventory.append(item)
```

Comment: wow, thank you so much! The second option seemed to solve my problem!

Comment: That `if` / `else` pattern is a common one, addressed by the standard libraries. Consider using `inventory = collections.defaultdict(int)`.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict